# Invalid table name error when creating a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Very new to SQL, but I thought that I had at least mastered how to make tables. I am trying to create the following table and get the error 'ORA-00903: invalid table name'. I'm not sure what is wrong.

```
Create table order (
order_id int,
item_type varchar(50),
item_name varchar(50),
item_price decimal(10,2),
primary key(order_id)
);
```

Comment: `order` is a reserved word.  Choose a different name for your table.

Comment: As a naming convention I use pluralis for table names. E.g. `orders`, since the table will store several orders (hopefully.)

Comment: 'order' is what it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I am testing this on Oralce Live SQL and it is ok as well as on my Oracle 12c Database EE, all you need to add are "". But even so, I would not recommend it to use reserved words for naming tables.

```
Create table "order" (
order_id int,
item_type varchar(50),
item_name varchar(50),
item_price decimal(10,2),
primary key(order_id)
);

insert into "order" values (1, 'Item', 'Name', '20.2');

select * from "order";
```